# White Screen After Bonobo Git Installation

Tags: asp.net, bonobo

I have been trying to install Bonobo Git server on windows 7 as a local server. I installed ASP.NET MVC4 enabled IIS. However, when I try to load the url

`http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/Home/LogOn`,

I just get a white screen. When I try the url

`http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/`,

I get this url

`http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/Home/LogOn?returnUrl=%2FBonobo.Git.Server%2FHome`

Any one know what this could be about. I suspect redirection issues but have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use anonymous authentication in IIS in case of bonobo application setup.
Check in authorization rule as well. Sometime if the bonobo application is set up in another parent application, it may inherit some rules from the parent website. You should not deny anonymous authentication rule over there.